# Relational MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table called users:

```
+----+---------+--------+----------------+----------------+----------+
| ID |  Name   |  Zip   |     Email      |     Phone      | Username |
+----+---------+--------+----------------+----------------+----------+
|  0 | Jill    |  33333 | jill@aol.com   | (123)123-1245  | idjill   |
|  1 | Jack    | 11111  | jack@aol.com   | (123)111-1111  | idjack   |
|  2 | Bob     |  66666 | bob@aol.com    | (123)222-2222  | idbob    |
|  3 | jMarie  |  12345 | jill@aol.com   | (123)123-1245  | none     |
+----+---------+--------+----------------+----------------+----------+
```

If I run `SELECT * FROM users WHERE Phone=(123)123-1245` will return both ID# 0 and 3.

What I would like to do is be able to select the user and but also return any other users that have the same phone or email but not zip code. So for example if I run `SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username= idjill` I'd like it to return user 0 and 3 because they both have the same phone number.

How can I do that? Thanks. If anyone has a better idea for a title to this post, please share. My first post, sorry.

Edit: I think I need to clarify my question a bit. So I have this select query right here:

```
SELECT *  FROM users WHERE Username = 'idjill' OR Email = 'idjill'
```

That perfectly returns ID 0, I would like it to return ID 0 and 3. Because the phone and the email match (I am using the same input to search between username and email).

How can I expand on this?

Comment: you can use union , one sql for specific user and union it with phone number

Comment: Your opening assertion is false.

Comment: @AhmedSunny how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using INNER JOIN like below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM users a INNER JOIN
 (SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='idjill') b
 ON (a.Phone=b.Phone OR a.Email=b.Email) AND a.Zip<>b.Zip;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested query like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE Phone=(SELECT PHONE 
             FROM users 
             WHERE Name='Jill') OR 
      Email=(SELECT Email 
             FROM users 
             WHERE Name='Jill');
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to implement this, I want to select by the user name or email and then return where is it redundant

Answer (score 0):

Nested  query can be used

```
Select * 
from users
where Phone = (select Phone from users where Username = "idjill");
```